# About the Fundamental Theorem of Vector Space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

In a book I found the following: "In a vector space $V$ of all real valued continuous functions of $x$ defined in the interval $[0,1]$, then

> $(f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(x),\forall f,g \in V $
>
> $(af)(x)=af(x) , \forall  a\in R, f\in V$"

But I am not getting how these above two conditions hold for contineous function. If someone gave an example, I'd really appreciate it, with best regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the definition of those continuous functions. It is not a result that can be derived. The function $\alpha f$ is *defined* to be the function which takes $x$ as input from the domain and spits out the value $\alpha f(x)$ in the codomain. Similarly for the function $f+g$. Proving that these functions are continuous (and hence belong to the domain $V$) so that these operations are closed is a result that **does** need to be proved though.

Comment: Is there any example so that we can express a function as $(f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(x)$

Comment: Let the function $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be given by $f(x)=x^2$ and let the function $g$ be given by $g(x)=\sin x$, then the function $f+g$ is given by $(f+g)(x)=x^2+\sin x$. Another example, let $0$ be the zero function (so $0(x)=0$ for all $x$), then $(f+0)(x)=f(x)+0(x)=f(x)+0$ so $f+0=f$ which means $0$ is an additive identity in this vector space.